# Decreasing disk size on Google Virtual Machine Web Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I am using Google Compute Engine VM for a web server. I currently have 3TB as disk space but want to bring it down to 1TB. Can someone tell me where I can do this from? Thanks.

Comment: Google Cloud does not support resizing persistent disk smaller. You will need third-party tools.

Answer (score 2):

As @John Hanley only increasing disk size is supported by [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/resize#DESCRIPTION):

> gcloud compute disks resize resizes a Compute Engine disk(s).
>
> Only increasing disk size is supported. Disks can be resized regardless of whether hey are attached.

I also found an answer in Serverfault that could help you with this topic [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/771905/google-compute-engine-shrinking-disks).
It uses fsarchiver tool in order to manage the boot disk resizing:

> If the disk is not a boot disk you can do the following:
>
> 1. add a new disk with the required size and format it.
> 2. mount the new disk
> 3. cp -r --preserve=all /mnt/disk1/. /mnt/disk2/
> 4. edit the /etc/fstab to mount the new disk instead the old one
>
> If you have standard disk and you want to shorten the cp time. You can
> first create new ssd disk from snapshot and copy it to 2T ssd disk.
> Then make a snapshot from the 2T disk and create a new 2T standard
> disk.
>
> If your disk is a boot disk, you can use a tool like fsarchiver:
>
> 1. Create an archive from the boot disk. `fsarchiver savefs /mnt/backup/boot_disk.fsa /dev/sda`
> 2. Restore the archive on the new disk `fsarchiver restfs /mnt/backup/boot_disk.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sdb`